# File Upload logic in View and Controller(MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor, controller

I want to implement a file uplaod logic in MVC, My view(cshtml) would contain something like this.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Upload files">
               <p><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" /> </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

And my controller would have the logic to save the file.

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"),
                                           Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
            uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

How do i link  the click event to trigger this controller? This was just a sample code I got in the net, LEt me know if it isn't right.

Thanks,
Adarsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will trigger this controller action by submitting a form, just like the MVC paradigm works.

In the view you should place this HTML in a form like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "<ControllerNameHere>", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{ 
        <p><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" /> </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>
}
```

This will trigger you controller.
I do not know how using the file as a parameter works. I usually use the `Request.Files` property in my controller.

Comment: Using Request.Files seem to be a better idea, Sample code please to use that:)

Comment: It's just a file collection so: 

`if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
   {
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in Request.Files)
    {
     // Do your file stuff
    }    
   }`

Comment: Thank you, in that case my controller will not accept any parameters. Would I be needing this line before theaction method [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
?

Comment: Indeed, your controller will not require any parameters anymore.
Yes, in this case the attribute is needed, the attribute is required when you are using the HTTP Post to acces the action which happens in this case since the formmethod is equal to post and thus invokes a POST.